# 505 Error when trying view image

Tags: html, wordpress

My site www.az-independent is getting a 505 error when trying to view an image. When I post them in a post they show up fine but when you want to look at them individually I get the 505 error.

this post http://www2.az-independent.com/2011/05/14/simply-superior-school-band/

shows the picture fine but when you click on the picture you get a 505 Error at this url

http://www2.az-independent.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Superior-rating-group-2.jpg

site built on wordpress if this helps

Comment: Do you have access to your error logs?

Comment: Where would I find this?

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, they *might* be accessible in the control panel, but they usually aren't. The server's administrator should know.

Answer (score 0):

MOst likely some sort of permission settings . but from this page

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E505.html

They mention unsupported html versions... what server is it? what daemon is it and version.

Maybe there is some restriction to download the file explicitly...

Answer (score 0):

I see `Error 500 - Internal Server Error`

To the best of my knowledge about Wordpress, this is a `.htaccess` problem. Try renaming the file to some other and reload the page. You might have changed permalink structure recently which might be causing this problem.